# Symfony 2: 404 Not Found Error when tryes to open /app_dev.php

Tags: symfony, nginx, http-status-code-404, symfony-2.1, profiler

I am getting this error message when try to open

/app_dev.php

```
An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found).

Do you want to open the profiler?
```

When I click ok, I am getting then the error:

```
app_dev.php/_profiler/5053258a822e1
```

and

```
404 Not found
```

I am using nginx

Thank you very much for your help.

EDIT: Here is the error log:

```
[error] 18369#0: *9 open() "/var/www/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/_wdt/5056f875afc98" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: symfony, request: "GET /app_dev.php/_wdt/5056f875afc98 HTTP/1.1", host: "symfony", referrer: "http://symfony/app_dev.php"
[error] 18369#0: *9 open() "/var/www/Symfony/web/404" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: symfony, request: "GET /app_dev.php/_wdt/5056f875afc98 HTTP/1.1", host: "symfony", referrer: "http://symfony/app_dev.php"
```

EDIT 2:

When i try to access app_dev.php the page opens but without the toolbar and when I try with app_dev.php/ I am getting the

```
**Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "404 Not Found".
Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused. **
```

error.

Comment: Can you post your nginx error log? (Not only what is printed into your browser!)

Comment: Thank you Florent, I changed my question

Comment: Resolved, Check my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30313196/1700429

Comment: I hope this link helps because it kinda the same.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299009/web-profiler-not-showing-up-in-dev/30300601

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this isn't exactly what you asked but might help future people who search for this issue, like @yvoyer suggested, my issue was the trailing slash too, my server used nginx and fpm, and in nginx // does not euqal /, so i had to do a bit of fixes on my virtual host conf and it worked fine after that. I'll just paste the conf for whoever needs it, or suggests a better one.

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri @pass_to_symfony;
    }

    location ~ /app_dev.php/ {
            try_files $uri @pass_to_symfony_dev;
    }

    location @pass_to_symfony{
            rewrite ^ /app.php?$request_uri last;
    }

    location @pass_to_symfony_dev{
            rewrite ^ /app_dev.php?$request_uri last;
    }

    location ~ ^/app(_dev)?\.php($|/) {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; # replace with your sock path
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, but I found out that the message was output when I typed `app_dev.php/` but not when requesting `app_dev.php` (Notice the trailing slash `/`).

I think it has to do with the Router, but Its just an educated guess

Answer (score 1):

My error was related to Nginx configuration (using symfony 3.1), and I just edited the recommended config for Nginx from Symfony:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

So, maybe it was because of symlinks, I don't know.

I copied a small part to Nginx Default config and edited to match all .php:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    # Symfony
    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }


    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

I would recommend sticking to Symfony recommendation for a production server.

Answer (score 0):

To display web debug toolbar in developer mode in Symfony2 page should have valid HTML.

Comment: Thank you @Rafal, but I am trying to open the app_dev.php file, it comes from the Symfony website. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution (more or less). I took another existing Symfony project and everything works fine now. I realy don't know why the Symfony standard release is not working in my case... If somebady needs the empty symfony project, I can upload the archive.

EDIT: here is the template of the working Symfony 2.0 : http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/372986/Symfony-tpl-zip.html

Comment: please upload the archive, i have same problem

Comment: Here is the Symfony template. Enjoy: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/372986/Symfony-tpl-zip.html If you find this usefull, please upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It happened in my dev environnement, so I comment the directive DirectoryIndex in my vhost config file, so now I get to my app with : `http://127.0.0.1/app_dev.php`
And no more errors about the profiler !
I use Symfony 2.3.x.

Answer (score -3):

please try paying attention to your .htaccess,  I had this problem too and I fixed mine.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app_dev.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]    ##### this is the part that you should tweak, have the .htaccess point the request to app_dev.php, since the routing.yml is empty initially
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]        ##### this is the part that you should tweak, have the .htaccess point the request to app_dev.php, since the routing.yml is empty initially
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the startpage to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Please read the entire post first: 
"I am using nginx
Thank you very much for your help." While your comment is appropriate to APACHE it will screw people up.