# Symfony 2.4: An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found)

Tags: symfony, configuration, routes

I just downloaded a fresh copy of Symfony 2.4.1 on a Debian 7.3.

The URL /Symfony/web/config.php opens correctly, but when I proceed to Configure, I get:

```
The requested URL /Symfony/web/app_dev.php/_configurator/ was not found on this server.
```

If I Bypass configuration and open /Symfony/web/app_dev.php
the page displays, but an error pops up saying:

```
An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found)
Do you want to open the profiler?
```

If I accept, I get:

```
The requested URL /Symfony/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/54a8bf was not found on this server.
```

In other questions (e.g. [Symfony 2: 404 Not Found Error when tryes to open /app_dev.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424864/symfony-2-404-not-found-error-when-tryes-to-open-app-dev-php)) people suggest to fiddle with the .htaccess file.
I even tried removing it, but it had no effect.

The apache log file shows:

```
File does not exist: /var/www/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/_wdt/54a8bf, referer: http://wwwtest.di.unipi.it/Symfony/web/app_dev.php
File does not exist: /var/www/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/54a8bf
```

So it looks like routing to any inner URL fails, despite the fact that the correct routing seems to be in place:

```
> app/console router:debug
[router] Current routes
 Name                      Method Scheme Host Path
 _wdt                      ANY    ANY    ANY  /_wdt/{token}
 _profiler_home            ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/
 _configurator_home        ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/
...
```

Comment: Found the solution.
One must add

   AcceptPathInfo On

to the apache vhost configuration or to .htaccess.

Comment: Please fix the typo in the title. ;)

Comment: If you found the solution can you answer your own question so that others may more easily benefit from the answer when looking.

Comment: Resolved, Check my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30313196/1700429

Comment: Anyone who is using nginx, this worked for me:
in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
replace
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
by
try_files $uri $uri/ /project-name/web/app_dev.php?$args;

I myself have my symfony project in ~/Projects/project-name
and a symlink in /usr/share/nginx/html/project-name pointing to my physical project.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed `memory_limit` in `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` to `512Mb` and debug toolbar started to work.

[Found solution for me here](http://share.ez.no/forums/ez-publish-5-platform/an-error-occurred-while-loading-the-web-debug-toolbar-404-not-found-.-do-you-want-to-open-the-profiler#comment86832)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to update my app_dev.php file to resemble the one in the Symfony2 repo

Notice the Debug class being used.  This wasn't used in older versions of symfony.  I updated this file and the javascript alert appears to be gone.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
/*
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
*/
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the following present in web/app_dev.php? The line below fixed it for me.

```
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache directive `DirectoryIndex app.php` does the tricks for me.
I put it in apache vhost conf with `AllowOverride None` to prevent override by **.htacces**.

Hope this help.