# Web Profiler not showing up in dev

Tags: php, symfony, profiler

Im using Symfony2 (const version="2.5.10") and using xampp with PHP version 5.5.19.

I got a problem that in my dev environment the profiler didn't show up.What could be the problem?

config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    translator: ~
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        ['MatrixEdiBundle', 'FOSUserBundle']
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Matrix\MatrixUserBundle\Entity\User
```

config_dev.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: %debug_toolbar%
    intercept_redirects: %debug_redirects%

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level:  debug
        console:
            type:   console
            bubble: false
        # uncomment to get logging in your browser
        # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
        #firephp:
        #    type:   firephp
        #    level:  info
        #chromephp:
        #    type:   chromephp
        #    level:  info

assetic:
    use_controller: %use_assetic_controller%

swiftmailer:
    #delivery_address: me@example.com
    disable_delivery: false
```

Comment: Don't you have any issues (alert opening in JS)? are you using the app_dev.php URL? don't you have a disabled conf in config_dev.yml with `profiler.enabled`: false?

Comment: hi, can you check my config.yml and config_dev.yml if there are problems?

Comment: Ensure you are on the dev environment. I had the same problem and it turned out I was on the prod environment locally. Dump out `{{ app.environment }}` to confirm.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The profiler toolbar needs `<body> ... </body>`. I guess you don't have it in your twig file(s).

[Profiler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/web_profiler.html)

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
```

Example twig file.

The line `{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}` will extend `app/Resources/views/base.html.twig` which injects default `<body>...</body>` into your custom twig files.

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
   Hello!
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I already change my config_dev.yml but still it does not show the profiler

Comment: Did you try to hard code `true` in the place of `%debug_toolbar%` to make it look like mine above?

Comment: yes ,, but still no luck ... instead I got an error like this "OutOfMemoryException: Error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2883686 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Editracker\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\DataCollector.php line 35"

Comment: These is a simple solution for that particular eeror. Just google it.

Comment: yeah, already tried that by increasing the memory_limit but still it gives me this error.

Comment: its already working when i try to another page with no error , thanks , but problem now is the out of memory

Comment: No problem. Open a new question and give the link so that I can answer it as well cos it is irrelevant to this current context.

Comment: here it is  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229637/out-of-memory-error-in-symfony/30229866

Comment: @BentCoder you are right. The body tag is required for the profiler to function. So, you either add body tag directly into your twig or extend base twig and overwrite its body component.

Answer (score 7):

In case your action not returning html code (e.g json API) and you want to use profiler:

Quick and dirty solution:

```
return new Response("<html><body>Debug data</body></html>");
```

Even quicker and dirtier solution - returning non `Response` type in controller will raise exception with profiler enabled response:

```
return 1;
```

If your application is running by Symfony `>=2.4` you can also use `X-Debug-Token` which contains debug token and `X-Debug-Token-Link` header which contains link to profiler page. If you want to use this method Chrome extension [Symfony2 Profiler shortcut](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/symfony2-profiler-shortcu/denlhphadllhcolhlbbbjmhkgbknmmon) will increase your user experience.

Comment: A shorter dirty solution `return new Response("<body></body>")`.

This is nice when you have actions that run but don't have to output anything

Answer (score 1):

have you enabled it in the config.yml or parameters.yml file? Are you in dev mode ? calling app_dev.php ?

also, it sometimes is minismised to a tidy square in the bottom right of the browser.

just some ideas that may help

Comment: In my case, it was idd a small Symfony icon in the right-bottom corner. After clicking on it, it was showing again. Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer above has indicated, the web profiler doesn't appear in simple twig files that have a  tag etc.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    Hello {{name}}.
{% endblock %}
```

shows the web profiler, but something simple like:

```
 <body>
    Hello {{name}}.
 </body>
```

would work, but not show the web profiler.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

The problem was in my routes definition. I has something like this:

```
load_home:
    path: /{page}
    defaults: {_controller: ExpatsBundle:Pages/Home:index, _format: html|json, page: 1}
    methods: GET
    requirements:
        page: \d+
```

So changing the _format: html|json to _format: html has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried all of the above to no avail. I switched windows in the browser to another application (with the wdt) and then switched back and all of a sudden it appeared (I had tried hard reload, etc, etc).