# symfony2 enabling dev environment debug tools(symfony profiler)

Tags: php, symfony

I forgot how to enable debug tools symfony2 provides with the dev environment. I'm sure I'm accessing the project through the app_dev.php, but I still don't get any debug tool wrapped around my site when I visit it from safari.
I'm planning to upgrade my project, but first I need to check whether I'm using deprecated functions, and the debug tools provide this info.

Comment: View the source of the generated html.  The html needs to be more or less valid before the profile toolbar will be shown.

Comment: Your answer is here. [Web Profiler not showing up in dev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299009/web-profiler-not-showing-up-in-dev/30300601#30300601)

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you need to have valid html for the profiler to show up.
First I removed everything in my base twig template and wrote 'test'. That wasn't enough. But the following was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <h>test</h>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I get the web toolbar I wanted.